# SQL: Storing Formatting in Data

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have always taught that it is incorrect to store formatted data in a table. Examples include:

```
+----------------+----+
| Data           | OK |
+----------------+----+
| 0370101234     |  ✓ |
+----------------+----+
| 03 7010 1234   |    |
+----------------+----+
| (03) 7010 1234 |    |
+----------------+----+
```

(Why doesn’t SO support tables?!)

The data is an Australian phone number which is generally 10 digits long, including the area code.

Including the format spacing or characters introduces ambiguity, so it is harder to sort or search.

The question is: **is there anything in the standards or in relational theory which covers this issue?**

**EDIT**

This isn’t a question about telephone numbers as such. I was illustrating a point with data that should be stored in its simplest form, even if it is to be displayed with formatting characters.

Other examples include the `$` sign which is clearly never stored with a currency value, and the thousands separator which has its own issues.

Comment: [so] should support tables; until that time, I use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: You should remove all this stuff about phone numbers if this isn't about phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting is meta-data.  If you include formatting in a column, you are mixing meta-data with data, which is clearly not a great idea.  I'm not a theory-guru, but I'd bet that is listed somewhere as a no-no.

For your specific example, which I know is only an example, you may actually want to store the format in a separate table.  Below is an example for SQL Server.  I must stress, this is only an example of how you might approach the problem by abstracting the format away from the data.  Please note, I'm *not* saying this is the best way, or even an appropriate way *for your scenario*.  Simply that it *MIGHT* work, as in the output shown below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.PhoneNumbers') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.PhoneNumbers;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.PhoneFormats') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.PhoneFormats;

CREATE TABLE dbo.PhoneFormats
(
    PhoneFormatID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_PhoneFormats
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , FormatDetails varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.PhoneFormats (FormatDetails)
VALUES ('(###) ###-####')
    , ('#### ###-###');

CREATE TABLE dbo.PhoneNumbers
(
    ClientID int NOT NULL
    , PhoneNumber bigint NOT NULL
    , PhoneFormatID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_PhoneNumber_Format
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES dbo.PhoneFormats(PhoneFormatID)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.PhoneNumbers (ClientID, PhoneNumber, PhoneFormatID)
VALUES (1, 2125551212, 1)
    , (2, 2300123456, 2);

SELECT pn.ClientID
    , FormattedNumber = FORMAT(pn.PhoneNumber, pf.FormatDetails)
FROM dbo.PhoneNumbers pn
    INNER JOIN dbo.PhoneFormats pf ON pn.PhoneFormatID = pf.PhoneFormatID;
```

the output:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| ClientID | FormattedNumber |
+----------+-----------------+
|        1 | (212) 555-1212  |
|        2 | 2300 123-456    |
+----------+-----------------+
```

This can be made to support currency symbols and thousands-separators exactly the same way.

Comment: Formatting certainly shouldn't be included in the data and I would almost argue against even storing it in a separate table. Different uses of the information may require different formatting. As a side note for the example; phone numbers are hard: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md. See #17 "Phone numbers contain only digits" which would break this. And #24 "Phone numbers are numbers". When I've needed to do specific formatting and validation for phone numbers I use the google libphonenumber library at the application layer.

Comment: In fact here in Australia mobile phone numbers begin with "04" and the zero is important. If you store that as an INT you will lose that digit. Phone numbers should be strings.

Comment: @RealityGone Phone numbers should be strings for another important reason: they don’t count or measure anything. As a result it should not be possible to perform arithmetic operations on them. In fact (in Australia) just about anything with the word “number” in it probably isn’t a number: Tax File Number, Personal Identification Number, International Standard Book Number, Registration Number, Australian Business Number, etc. Most of them use mostly numeric characters, but that’s all.

Comment: I guess my main point was that most formatting tasks can be difficult and use case specific and shouldn't be stored as part of the data. Especially if you consider data validation as part of the formatting exercise. (How do you format something that is invalid?) Thus formatting is better off left to the data presentation layer. But if you need to have a common formatting come from the database this is a good solution that allows for adding additional formatting methods. (Except for the part where it stores the number as an INT.)

Comment: @RealityGone - my answer was not about providing a canonical way of handling *phone numbers*.  Yes, I realize phone numbers need a lot of special handling, especially if you're going to actually use them to phone someone.  The example is merely meant to show how you *might* separate formatting from data.

Comment: @Manngo - just because you don't want to be able to perform mathematics on a "number" doesn't mean it shouldn't be stored as a number.  If we're only talking about a couple hundred rows, sure store that in a `varchar(512)` column, but if you start storing *lots* of rows, the difference in byte size of a `char(10)` compared to an `int` offers a 60% savings. So it does matter, some times.

Comment: @RealityGone I show how to use that libphonenumber in my own answer in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for telephone numbers **only numeric values are needed**.

You know this because when you key in the telephone number you do not include the non-numeric characters.

The formatting using characters such as `+ ( ) - . x` are strictly to help the person using the number to have a useful pattern to help remember and enter the numeric values.

The formatting of the number may reduce the frequency of mistakes when entering a phone number.

So, the answer to your question seems to depend on the non-identical needs of:

1. The needs of **the telephone exchange**.
2. The needs of **the person entering the number**.

Likely other numbers in businesses, government, et cetera have similar peculiarities as they straddle the electronic and human realms.

By this time in the world, of course, you can also send emails from your telephone that usually use the `MyContact@xxx.yyy` format.  Of course they are not *Phone Numbers*.

**If you ever want to format a Phone Number for consistency's sake you might find this useful:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wasn’t asking about telephone numbers as such. It was just an illustration of the difference between actual data and formatting.

Comment: Ok.  It seems that you were not asking a question but making an observation. Coping with the disparity is still an issue for some people.

Comment: No, I was asking whether, more than being a good rule of thumb, there is some standard or theory which reinforces this?

Comment: *The formatting using characters such as + ( ) - . x are strictly to help the person using the number to have a useful pattern to help remember and enter the numeric values.* is simply not true, for instance. `ext` and `~` in the E.123 standard.

Comment: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md

Answer (score 0):

## PostgreSQL

When possible always use the canonical form. The more normalized the form the better. If there is a standard, use it. For this problem, let's use Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/cpp), by proxy of [pg-libphonenumber](https://github.com/blm768/pg-libphonenumber).

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_libphonenumber;
```

This currently installs the `phone_number` type which has comparison operators and functions. It stores the number in an international canonical form. This is the best compromise in my opinion.

```
parse_phone_number('textnumber', 'CountryCode');
```

Because we can tell when phone numbers equal each other and we provide an internal normal form, we can do this..

```
SELECT parse_phone_number('03 7010 1234', 'AU') = parse_phone_number('(03) 7010 1234', 'AU');
```

(returns true). This also means that `DISTINCT` works so we can do this to get the effect you seem to want above.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT DISTINCT parse_phone_number(ph, 'AU')
  FROM ( VALUES
    ('0370101234'),
    ('03 7010 1234'),
    ('(03) 7010 1234')
  ) AS t(ph);
SELECT 1
```

That puts in..

```
 parse_phone_number 
--------------------
 +61 3 7010 1234
(1 row)
```

## A bloody mess in the outback.

As it pertains to this question and AU, it's interesting that libphonenumber doesn't show the `0` before the `03`, but this is the canonical international representation.

> To access numbers in the same area, it is necessary only to dial the eight digits concerned. To access a number in another "Area" it is necessary firstly to dial the "Trunk Access Code" of 0, followed by the area code (2, 3, 7 or 8) and then the specific "Local" number.

So, you may have to dial `0` from within AU to get to a different trunk, but you don't have to dial it anywhere else in the world. From my reading, that means to determine whether or not you have to dial `03` first, you have to know where the dialing is dialing from. Depending where they're coming from, they may not `03`, or just `3`, or nothing at all (if they're in the same "trunk"). Funnnn.

Answer (score -1):

No, as far I know at least data formating is metadata and here it dependes on context.

For example, if you are storing phone number around the world the formating will be part of the data because they will vary a lot. In fact not even ascii will sufice and your data will be prone to user typos.

If you are storing a US zip code you just need the number. The application UI can handle all the formating, for input and output and it can deliver sanitized data always for the DB.

If you are storing dates you will use a date type and again let application handle formating AND localization issues.

If you are storing phone number form a country where each region have it's local area code you can put that local codes in a separate table.